# Event в unity animation

Tags: unity3d, анимация, события

Делаю анимацию через аниматор. В конце анимации есть event. Анимация работает стабильно. Изначальная она 2 секунды, решил увеличить время, перетащил подальше. Теперь перестал работать event. Не пойму в чём может быть причина этого.

Comment: Event'ы в анимациях unity очень ненадежная вещь, и нет гарантий что они будут вызваны, по возможности лучше использовать привязку к длительности анимации или Animation State Machines.

Comment: По поводу ненадёжной вещи - бред. По моему, как раз, привязка к длительности - это не лучший вариант.

Comment: @Taras Lazoriv LazeR, не знаю как сейчас, но в том же 2016 году, если судить по форумам, с этим было много проблем [например](https://forum.unity.com/threads/animation-not-allways-stops-at-the-end.440613/) да и в общем количество тем по этому поводу наводит на мысль что система всё-таки дает сбои, опять же, как сейчас обстоят дела с этим точно не уверен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть в Unity такая штука, называется [State Machine Behaviours](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/5-pre-order-beta/state-machine-behaviours). Это скрипт, который можно повесить внутрь аниматора. Он отлавливает переходы между анимациями и вызывает об этом события.

Грубо говоря, вы можете подписаться на событие стейт машины и выполнить вызов чего-то после того, как анимация будет проиграна или перед началом её проигрыша.
Думаю, в вашем случае идеально подойдёт для решения проблемы.

Comment: Хорошее решение